# Drawing Sierpinski's Triangle in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, geometry, awt

I'm having some issues with my code to draw a Sierpinski's Triangle (or Sierpinski's Gasket), but I'm not sure what the problem is. The lines for the triangle are drawn, then all the fractals, then it disappears. Help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SierpinskiGasket extends JFrame {

Point x=new Point(5,545),
      y=new Point(300,25),
      z=new Point(605,545),
      current=x, target;
private int count=0;

public SierpinskiGasket () {
    super("Sierpinski Gasket");
    setSize(610,550);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    if(count==0) {
    g.drawLine(x.x,x.y,y.x,y.y);
    g.drawLine(x.x,x.y,z.x,z.y);
    g.drawLine(z.x,z.y,y.x,y.y);
    } else {
        while(count<10000) {
            int choice=(int)(Math.random()*3);
            switch(choice) {
                case 0: target=x; break;
                case 1: target=y; break;
                case 2: target=z; break;
                default: System.exit(0);
            }
            current=midpoint(current,target);
            g.drawRect(current.x,current.y,5,5);
            repaint();
            count++;
        }
    }
    count++;
}

public Point midpoint(Point a, Point b) {
    return new Point((Math.round(a.x+b.x)/2),
                     (Math.round(a.y+b.y)/2));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SierpinskiGasket();
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Don't extend from a top level container (like `JFrame`), you're not adding anything of benefit to it.
2. Avoid painting to top level containers. Instead use something like `JPanel`.
3. Avoid overriding `paint`, use `paintComponent` instead. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

This is not how paint works (and I'm not going to try to rewrite your code to make it).

Paint is called in response to a number of events when the repaint system decides that part or whole of the UI needs to be updated.  Paints are destructive, that is, when paint is called, the `Graphics` will be completely refreshed, requiring you to "rebuild" the output from scratch.

Instead.

Write a recursive algorithm that can paint to something like `BufferedImage` and draw that within the `paintComponent`...

**Updated**

Painting in Swing is controlled by the `RepaintManager`, it is it's responsibility to determine what and when to repaint the screen.  You seem to be thinking the `paint` is something your control, when it's not.

You need to either be prepared to completely repaint the UI or have a buffer prepared that you can paint onto the UI, depending on your needs.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SierpinskisGasket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SierpinskisGasket();
    }

    public SierpinskisGasket() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            BaseShape base = new BaseShape(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()));
            Rectangle bounds = base.getBounds();
            int x = (getWidth() - bounds.width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - bounds.height) / 2;
            base.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));
            g2d.fill(base);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class BaseShape extends Path2D.Float {

        public BaseShape(float size) {

            float subSize = size / 2f;
            Triangle top = new Triangle(subSize);
            top.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance((size - subSize) / 2, 0));
            append(top, false);

            Triangle left = new Triangle(subSize);
            left.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, subSize));
            append(left, false);

            Triangle right = new Triangle(subSize);
            right.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(subSize, subSize));
            append(right, false);

        }

    }

    public class Triangle extends Path2D.Float {

        public Triangle(float size) {

            moveTo(size / 2f, 0);
            lineTo(size, size);
            lineTo(0, size);
            closePath();

        }

    }

}
```

You should never be calling anything from `paint` that could alter the state of the UI and trigger another `repaint`, otherwise you are going to end up in a end cycle of repaints that will eventually consume your CPU.

You should also take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: This was really not helpful to me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm primarily concerned why the fractals are not being drawn.

Comment: You're also responding to an individual state or moment in time.  The `Graphics` context is wiped clear on each new paint cycle, meaning that anything your previously painted to it, no longer exists.  You would need to completely rebuild the output on each cycle.  When I ran your code, I got a `count` of `1`, `1001`, but nothing was shown on the screen, because on `1001` iteration, it was wiped clean...I'm sure I said that (not in so many words)

Comment: I appreciate your input and that you took the time to address my mistakes. It should be noted that I am a beginner programmer and that I know very little about AWT or String. I've only been on the subject of AWT and Swing in my Java class for about 3 weeks. In my Java textbook, where I got this exercise, the way I went about coding this is basically the same as what is shown. There  is no mention in my text about a single thing you mentioned in your answer. I'm not doubting your knowledge, however, I imagine I'm supposed to solve the problem similarly to how I did- for this class, at least.

Comment: @user2361122: If you don't mind, what's the name of the Java textbook that has you using a paint method?  That advice is at least 10 years out of date.

Comment: Absolute Java, 5th Edition by Walter Savitch

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think I see what you're saying. FOOM, in his answer below, pointed out the error that fixed my main problem (why the fractals were not being drawn). Now I see that after everything is drawn, it then disappears.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = ((int)Math.random()*3);    
System.out.println("i:"+i);
```

When I run the above, I always get 0

So your "choice" variable is always zero...probably has something to do with your problem?

Comment: Wow! What a stupid mistake! That fixed it... kind of. Now the fractals are drawn but then disappear once finished.

Comment: I'm no swing expert, but I reckon MadProgrammer's onto something when he/she says " The Graphics context is wiped clear on each new paint cycle, meaning that anything your previously painted to it, no longer exists" - that seems to describe what's happening to you, so I'd have a look at his answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Just removing the `repaint()` call fixed it.